# Disable Edit & Delete Option in Odoo 11

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12

I'm a new Odoo developer I created a simple request module in Odoo 11 that will make employee request for stock but when the request is saved and submitted I don't want the request to be edited and deleted by users.
I have tried the security rules `perm_write = 0` and `edit` option lost but users are not able to submit the request and help, please?

```
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_stock_request_user,stock request user,model_stock_request,group_stock_request_user,1,0,1,0
```

Comment: please can you calrify your question, adding a sample code well edited ?

Comment: @sodjsn26fr i want hide edit and delete button when request state change, in order for users not to edit or delete request after request submitted for approval.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sudo() in your submit function to bypass access right

`self.env["stock.request"].sudo().state = "submitted"`

And further hide the button if you want

`<button name="submit()" string="Submit" type="object" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', '=', 'submitted')]}/>"`

Comment: This is my submit function.
@api.multi
    def button_submit_valid(self):
        if self.env.context.get('request_id'):
            request = self.env['ompin.request'].browse(self.env.context.get('request_id'))
            request.write({'state': 'callcenter', 'accepted_by': self.accepted_by.id,'valid_date': self.valid_date})

This is the error i get when i try to submit request.
Sorry, you are not allowed to modify this document. Please contact your system administrator if you think this is an error.

(Document model: ompin.request) - (Operation: write, User: 9)

Comment: You can try this
``` 
request.sudo().write({'state': 'callcenter', 'accepted_by': self.accepted_by.id,'valid_date': self.valid_date}) 
```

Comment: I'm still getting this error
Sorry, you are not allowed to modify this document. Please contact your system administrator if you think this is an error.

(Document model: ompin.request) - (Operation: write, User: 9)

it's because i set security perm_write = 0? and i don't want users to edit
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_ompin_request,access.ompin.request,model_ompin_request,,1,0,1,0

Comment: put sudo() after your recordset will help you bypass access rights checks, can you share more code?

Comment: class OrangeRequest(models.Model):
 
    _name = "ompin.request"


    state = fields.Selection([('new', 'NEW'),('callcenter', 'Call Center'),('pinreset', 'PIN RESET'),('invalid', 'INVALID'),
                            ], default='new')
name = fields.Char(string='Request ID', copy=False)
    current_user = fields.Many2one('res.users','Requester', default=lambda self: self.env.uid, readonly="True")
    phone = fields.Char(related='current_user.phone', string='Mobile', readonly="True") 
email = fields.Char(related='current_user.email', string='Email', readonly="True")

Comment: cus_number = fields.Char(string='Customer Number', required=True)
    fullname = fields.Char(string='Customer Name', required=True)

    accepted_by = fields.Many2one('res.users','Accepted By', default=lambda self: self.env.uid, readonly="True")
    valid_date =fields.Datetime(string="Accepted Date", default=lambda *a: datetime.now(),readonly=True) 

    @api.multi
    def button_submit_back_office(self):
        for record in self:
            record.write({'state': 'callcenter'})

Comment: class ValidRequest(models.Model):
    _name = "valid.callcenter.request"


    accepted_by = fields.Many2one('res.users','Accepted By', default=lambda self: self.env.uid, readonly="True")
    valid_date =fields.Datetime(string="Accepted Date", default=lambda *a: datetime.now(),readonly=True)

Comment: @api.multi
    def button_submit_valid(self):
        if self.env.context.get('request_id'):
            request = self.env['ompin.request'].browse(self.env.context.get('request_id'))
            request.write({'state': 'pinreset', 'accepted_by': self.accepted_by.id, 'valid_date': self.valid_date})

Comment: Please change `request.write({})` to `request.sudo().write({})` every place you want


 `record.write({})` to `record.sudo().write({})`

Comment: I have tried and not work for me, I end up using attrs="{'readonly': [('state', '!=', 'new')]}" on all field.
Thanks for the support i appreciate.